# Most efficient method for reading/writing image files as numpy array

Tags: python, performance, numpy, scipy, python-imaging-library

I am wondering what the most efficient methods for reading/writing image and PDF files as numpy arrays for processing.

So far I have seen `scipy.ndimage.imread` and using `PIL` and numpy,  which yeild the following results:

```
import os
import glob
from scipy.ndimage import imread
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import timeit
iters = 2
def scipy_fun():
    for x in glob.glob("*.jpg"):
        px = imread(x)
def PIL_fun():
    for x in glob.glob("*.jpg"):
        with Image.open(x) as im:
            px = np.array(im)

print(timeit.Timer(scipy_fun).timeit(number=iters))
print(timeit.Timer(PIL_fun).timeit(number=iters))
```

running the script shows similar results with marginally better from scipy:

```
2.8794324089019234
3.0174482765699095
```

Are there any faster ways to do this?

Comment: Another library you could try is [imageio](http://imageio.github.io/).

Comment: Thanks! `imageio` appears to be a very good library.  The output was `scipy: ~4 secs
imageio: ~3 secs
PIL: ~4 secs`

Answer (score 1):

First, do this

```
pip install pdf2image
```

Then,

```
import numpy as np
from pdf2image import convert_from_path as read
import PIL
import cv2
#pdf in the form of numpy array to play around with in OpenCV or PIL
img = np.asarray(read('path to the pdf file')[0])#first page of pdf
```

Comment: This approach is hell a lot smoother and more efficient than first saving the `img` and then using `opencv` to read it, so well done *Ali* and *Santhosh*!